# change Z index wpf canvas element from cs file

Tags: wpf, canvas, path

I have Paths inside my Canvas and I want to change the Z index of one of the paths from cs file! that is clicked I can get it like (sender as Path) but I cant change its Z location and I resize this path but the problem is it stays under other paths I want to put it over them.  So what is your suggestion? How can I set the Z index property of the Path from my "myCanvas" canvas? Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attached property:

```
Canvas.SetZIndex((Path)sender, 9999);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Canvas.SetZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setzindex%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method. Also take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/06/13/controlling-zorder-using-the-zindex-property.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like most attached property, you set it with static method of the parent class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setzindex(v=vs.95).aspx